# What are these Photos and Settings windows in Windows 10

Tags: winapi

I wrote a small program to dump the window sizes of all visible windows with titles on my Windows 10 machine. I retrieved the windows in the usual way with EnumWindows/FindWindows, and I fetched only windows with non-empty title strings and with the WS_VISIBLE style attribute. For the most part, the listing produced all the windows I could see on my screen, in the appropriate pixel locations, with appropriate pixel sizes (x, y, width, and height).

BUT.. there were 4 additional windows listed (windows 11 through 14): two titled 'Photos' and two titled 'Settings', with positions and sizes as follows:

```
  11 'Photos'
      Left 0 Top 8 Width 2560 Height 1400
  12 'Photos'
      Left 994 Top 11 Width 561 Height 828
  13 'Settings'
      Left 0 Top 32 Width 1200 Height 900
  14 'Settings'
      Left 355 Top 63 Width 1216 Height 940
```

These are not visible to the eye, even though they exist and have the VISIBLE window attribute and a title string.

The only thing "unusual" about my Desktop is that I'm running a program called Fences that groups my icons into groups.  But there are 11 icon groups, not 4. And if it was the issue, I would expect 11 additional weird windows with the same title, not the 2xPhotos and 2xSettings that I see in the list output. So it seems unlikely that the little icon-grouping Fences program is producing the effect.

Can anyone explain what is going on? Could they be transparent system windows of some kind, and if so, for what purpose? I've searched the net but have come up empty-handed. Thank you.

UPDATE 1: After RbMn's comment pointing to another similar post

The other post suggested that the mystery windows were Windows Store windows and gave some screenshots showing that the top-level window of a pair would have `ApplicationFrameWindow` as a class name and the first child `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.` And that part of the post was true in my case (see the trace output below).

```
  9 'Photos'
      Left 0 Top 8 Width 2560 Height 1400
      ClassName:  Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow
  10 'Photos'
      Left 994 Top 11 Width 561 Height 828
      ClassName:  ApplicationFrameWindow
  11 'Settings'
      Left 0 Top 32 Width 1200 Height 900
      ClassName:  Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow
  12 'Settings'
      Left 355 Top 63 Width 1216 Height 940
      ClassName:  ApplicationFrameWindow
```

But, the other post said that "This suggests an answer to your question: If a top-level window is of class ApplicationFrameWindow, iterate it's children. If the first child has class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow, the window is visible, otherwise, it is not (i.e. it is phantom)." My 4 mystery windows seem "phantom" to me because I can't see them, even though they have the WS_VISIBLE attribute.

UPDATE 2: DWMWA_CLOAKED

The other post talked about cloaked windows and how to fetch the cloaked status from the desktop window manager API function DwmGetWindowAttribute (.... CLOAKED...).  A code snippet was provided. I used it to fetch the cloaked status of my 4 mystery windows, but they all came back as NOT cloaked (even though I could not see them). If a window is cloaked, the status is non-zero and can be 1 (cloaked_app), 2 (cloaked_shell), or 4 (cloaked_inherited). In my case, the status was 0 (no cloaking) in all 4 cases.

```
  9 'Photos'
      Left 0 Top 8 Width 2560 Height 1400
      ClassName:  Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow
      Cloaked:    no
  10 'Photos'
      Left 994 Top 11 Width 561 Height 828
      ClassName:  ApplicationFrameWindow
      Cloaked:    no
  11 'Settings'
      Left 0 Top 32 Width 1200 Height 900
      ClassName:  Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow
      Cloaked:    no
  12 'Settings'
      Left 355 Top 63 Width 1216 Height 940
      ClassName:  ApplicationFrameWindow
      Cloaked:    no
```

So, although these are system (Windows Store?) windows, it is still a mystery why they are not visible if they have the WS_VISIBLE attribute and are not cloaked. (I'm guessing that maybe CLOAKED tells the DWM not to render the windows on the screen?)

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but you may have already checked this. Do your virtual desktops have anything on them. `Ctrl`+`Win`+`Right` to access and `Ctrl`+`Win`+`Left` to return to your "normal" desktop

Comment: try next call on this `hwnd` - `DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_CLOAKED, &CloakedVal, sizeof( CloakedVal ))`. guess you got `DWM_CLOAKED_SHELL` in `CloakedVal` - The window was cloaked by the Shell.

Comment: Gregory, sorry, no, I don't use virtual desktops. RbMm, wow, you're very good to find the possible duplicate post - I searched but found nothing using my keywords. There are several really good ideas to follow up in that post. I looked in Spy++ at my windows and saw a System...Core..something, so I thought they might be system windows. From the post, it looks like they well might be. I will update this thread after I find out more. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @RbMm: Is this a strict requirement? It's certainly an obvious optimization, but the documentation doesn't seem to require the `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` style for the `DWMWA_CLOAKED` flag to work.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, you right - `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` really not mandatory and not related to `DWMWA_CLOAKED` flag.